# CSS specific alignment need

Tags: html, css

I am quite new to html/css, and I spent some time writing my own website from scratch. I have understood the very basics of the thing, but many subtleties are still unclear in my mind. Currently, I am unable to achieve a specific feature on my website, and I was hoping that maybe some of you would come up with a simple solution.

[Here](http://s1319.photobucket.com/user/Jonathan_Viquerat/media/2_zpsac6a873d.png.html) is what my website looks like: the colors are here to make things clearer. The four blocks "converge" toward the focal point. The top left part "Research interests" is dedicated to contain short descriptions, while the top right part "PhD thesis" is dedicated to contain either large texts or pictures. From now on, I will only focus on the top right part, where my problem occurs.

Green part :

```
#maindisplay
{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    width: 66.6%;
    height: 80.0%;
    float: right;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Red part :

```
#maindisplay article
{
    background-color: red;
    font-family: Conv_verdana, sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 1.5%;
    top: 10%;
    width: 70.0%;
    height: 75.0%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Dark gray part :

```
#maindisplay p
{
    background-color: gray;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 90%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -30px;
}
```

I get my bottom alignment for the #maindisplay paragraphs by absolute positioning them inside the relative positioned article (and therefore, the "overflow: auto;" is here totally useless). When the text is short enough, this works like a charm and the result is *exactly* what I want it to be. However, when the text is longer, or when the screen is smaller (typically, my laptop), I would like things to look like [this](http://s1319.photobucket.com/user/Jonathan_Viquerat/media/3_zps062fda1d.png.html) : the top of the text appears first, and a scroll bar is available. When the text is scrolled to the bottom, the bottom of the scrolled text is aligned with the bottom of the top left part, as it is in the first picture. This is achieved by setting :

```
#maindisplay p
{
    background-color: gray;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 90%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

So here is my problem : I would like the first behavior when the text is short enough, and the second behavior when it is longer than the #maindisplay article div. I was hoping that this could be done in a css-only way but I have looked for quite some time and now I am unsure about this (please note that I know precisely nothing about the javascript/jquery stuff). I am not allergic to tables, but I just don't see how to use them here.

Please let me know if there is anything unclear about this, and thanks in advance for your answers !

Comment: Try to avoid more text in your Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a fiddle making what you need http://jsfiddle.net/7N6Gp/ or http://jsfiddle.net/7N6Gp/1/

you need 2 div's for this one

the `holder div` that has `position: relative;`

```
.holder {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;   
}
```

and a `content div` that has `overflow: auto` and `max-height`

```
.content {
    width: 500px;
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

with your code . you need to wrap content in a `div` not `p` . `p` should only contain text or inline elements . and from your pictures it looks like it contains titles and other paragraphs (block elements)

`#maindisplay p` change into `#maindisplay div.content`

Comment: I have struggled so much time with this one. This is *exactly* what I wanted. Many many thanks.